# Resampling/interpolating/extrapolating columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, interpolation, resampling

I am interested in knowing how to interpolate/resample/extrapolate columns of a pandas dataframe for pure numerical and datetime type indices.  I'd like to perform this with either straight-forward linear interpolation or spline interpolation.

Consider first a simple pandas data frame that has a numerical index (signifying time) and a couple of columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), index=np.arange(0,20,2))
print(df)

       0         1
0   0.937961  0.943746
2   1.687854  0.866076
4   0.410656 -0.025926 
6  -2.042386  0.956386
8   1.153727 -0.505902
10 -1.546215  0.081702
12  0.922419  0.614947
14  0.865873 -0.014047
16  0.225841 -0.831088
18 -0.048279  0.314828
```

I would like to resample the columns of this dataframe over some denser grid of time indices which possibly extend beyond the last time index (thus requiring extrapolation).

Denote the denser grid of indices as, for example:

```
t = np.arange(0,40,.6)
```

The interpolate method for a pandas dataframe seems to interpolate only nan's and thus requires those new indices (which may or may not coincide with the original indices) to already be part of the dataframe.  I guess I could append a data frame of nans at the new indices to the original dataframe (excluding any indices appearing in both the old and new dataframes) and call interpolate and then remove the original time indices.  Or, I could do everything in scipy and create a new dataframe at the desired time indices.

Is there a more direct way to do this?

In addition, I'd like to know how to do this same thing when the indices are, in fact, datetimes.  That is, when, for example:

```
df.index = np.array('2015-07-04 02:12:40', dtype=np.datetime64) + np.arange(0,20,2)
```